# mysql .net update stored procedure cannot be found

Tags: .net, mysql, stored-procedures

i am using mysql with .net framework 4.0 . i have stored procedures in my database. my stored procedure calling is:

```
public DataTable addProductMenu(int myid, string itemname)
    { 
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter("updateProductMenu", connection);
        adapt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("myid", myid);
        adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("itemname", itemname);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        adapt = null;
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            return dt;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

code is working when i use insert, select commands in database but not update. i tested my procedure in mysql query browser and its working fine.

Also tried this code for just update query

```
public DataTable updateProductMenu(int myid, string itemname)
    { //Veritabanından ürün menüsündeki başlığı güncelle

        MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        string cmdText = "updateProductMenu";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnx);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MySqlParameter param;
        param = new MySqlParameter("?myid", MySqlDbType.Int32);
        param.Value = myid;
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new MySqlParameter("?itemname", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        param.Value = itemname;
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        adapter = null;
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            return dt;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

both have the error

```
Procedure or function '`updateProductMenu`' cannot be found in database '`mydatabase`'.
```

ADDED-----------------------------------------

the user has all privileges. i checked again.

here is my connectionstring in web.config file...:

```
<add name="maktesConn" connectionString="Server = myserver; Port =3306; Database =mydatabase; Uid =mysqlsanatkar; Pwd =*123qsanatq*/;" />
```

.......and here is part of my class.....:

```
public class Mimages
{
    private string connectionString;

    public Mimages()
    {
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["maktesConn"].ToString();
    }
```

and here is part of my stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mydatabase.updateProductMenu $$
CREATE PROCEDURE mydatabase.updateProductMenu (myid INT, itemname VARCHAR(60))
BEGIN
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.... mysql connector for .net was 6.3.7. i updated it to 6.4.4. Now all my stored procedures are working. Thanks for your reply "bang" btw.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you are able to call other stored procedures with the same code or just select and insert commands ?

Have you checked caps on both database name and stored procedure name? Depending on settings MySql will convert names to lower case and become case sensitive.

Checked security for db current ?

Comment: i am able to call other stored procedures with same code yeah. When my stored procedure has update query in it, it is not working and show that error i said before. i checked caps they are ok. but i dont understand what do you mean by security?

Comment: Check that the mysql user account you're using has EXECUTE privileges.
Also dubbelcheck that caps are correct in code AND connection string!